# Kafka Connect cluster infinite workers rebalancing at startup

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I've successfully deployed a standalone Connect Worker and now I would like to scale it to three workers deployed on three different machines on a local network, let's say that their hostnames are `server0, server1 and server2` respectively.

So I've compiled this connect-distributed.properties file on each machine like this:

```
bootstrap.servers = server0:9092,server1:9092,server2:9092
group.id=connect-group
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable = true
offset.storage.replication.factor=3
offset.storage.partitions=25
config.storage.replication.factor=3
status.storage.replication.factor=3
status.storage.partitions=5
offset.flush.interval.ms=30000
listeners=HTTP://[hostnane]:8083
plugin.path=[connectors_dir]
```

Most of the time only one server boots up correctly while the remaining two they just start an infinite rebalancing process that from the log looks like this:

```
[timestamp] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, group=connect-group] Herder started (org.apache .kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:364)
...
[timestamp] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, group=connect-group] Discovered group coordinator server0:9092 (....)
[timestamp] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, group=connect-group] Rebalance started (...)
[timestamp] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, group=connect-group] (Re-)joining group (....)
[timestamp] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, group=connect-group] Succesfully joined goup with generation Generation {generationId= .....}
[timestamp] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, group=connect-group] Succesfully synced group in generation Generation {generationId= ....}
[timestamp] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, group=connect-group] Joined group at generation 7 with protocol version2 and got assignment: Assignment{error=0, leader= ....} with rebalance delay:0 (..... )
[timestamp] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, group=connect-group] Catching up to assignment's config offset. (....(
[timestamp] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, group=connect-group] Current config state offset -1 is behind group assignment 1, reading to end of config log (....)
[timestamp] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, group=connect-group] Finisched reading to end of lof and updated config spanshot, new config log offset: -1 (....)
[timestamp] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, group=connect-group] Current config state offset -1 is behind group assignment 1, reading to end of config log (...)
[timestamp] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, group=connect-group] Finished reading to end of log and updated config snapshot, new config offset: -1 (...)
[timestamp] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, group=connect-group] Current config state offset -1 is behind group assignment 1, reading to end of config log (...)
.....
ad infinitum
```

I checked if every connect-distributed.properties file had the same `group.id` which they do.

I also tried to write the hostname of every Connect worker in the `listeners` attribute to no avail, that just had led to other issues and I still get the same infinite rebalancing issue.

Finally, I tried to comment back the `offset.storage.partitions` and `status.storage.partitions` but of course it led to nothing.

Comment: `Current config state offset -1  .... new config log offset: -1` seems like it is unable to actually read any data. + `group=connect=group` seems like you have an equal sign in the group name?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I'm not able to directly copy-paste or transfer the logs from my workstation to the machine from which I'm writing here so everything you see it's been written by hand.
After I wrote that I copy pasted it without noticing the typos
Now it should be clearer

Comment: Still, seems like the configs aren't being read. Connect standalone doesn't use those topics. Do you have authentication on your brokers? If so, you're missing configuration for that, but you're saying a single `connect-distributed` process is able to start okay?

Comment: > Do you have authentication on your brokers?
Not at this time.


> but you're saying a single connect-distributed process is able to start okay?
Yes, I even tried to run a single connect broker with these settings on each different machine one at the time.


I even managed to exchange messages from one database to another with a single worker paired with Debezium (Source) and JDBC (Sink) but everything breaks once I try to scale up to three workers.

Almost every time one of them boots up fine while the other two rebalance infinitely, I seldom managed to start a functional cluster.

Comment: The rebalancing is expected, but it shouldn't cause errors (or infinite loops), unless the configs are inconsistent. I assume you are manually installing on each machine? I generally recommend using tools like [Ansible](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-ansible) for this, or Kubernetes / Docker Swarm with containers

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to add that I've been actually using Ansible from the beginning.

Comment: I also took a look at the connect-distributed.properties files that are deployed on the server after being automatically editet by Jinja2 and the only differences between them are: the listeners list (on each worker it's listed its http address) and the offset, config and status topics are different for each worker.
I'm pretty sure that I'm supposed to not bind these topics to multiple workers.

Comment: Those 3 topics must be the same for each worker in the cluster. That's how they share state and configuration. The listeners (and host.name) are how the workers forward client http requests for connector creation

Comment: Are you sure? That looks like a no-no according to this
https://rmoff.net/2019/11/22/common-mistakes-made-when-configuring-multiple-kafka-connect-workers/

Comment: Ok I've tried what you suggested and it turns out you were right, I've likely misunderstood what the article meant.
Many thanks!

Comment: You only have one Connect Cluster of multiple workers that must all share the same topics. That point is talking about different Connect Clusters (unique `group.id`, for example, with the same `bootstrap.servers`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after getting some help here it turns out that I misunderstood section number 3 of [this article](https://rmoff.net/2019/11/22/common-mistakes-made-when-configuring-multiple-kafka-connect-workers/) as I set a different configuration topic (offset, config, status) for every Connect Worker in the cluster.

Once I bound the same topics to every worker it started working well.